# React - this is undefined in constructor

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and working on some exercises. Inside YTSearch when I am using this, i get a message that this is undefined. But the tutorial instructor which i am looking at has the same code and it is working for him. Can someone help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';

const API_KEY = "AIzaSyCDclF-xo-YjMt48H8WMsnebncKmU3jsQA";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 'videos' : []};
        YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, function(data){
            console.log(data);
            console.log(this);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return <input />;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.container'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a context issue, you forgot to `bind` the callback method, to use this keyword, you need to bind it, use this:

```
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 'videos' : []};
        YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, function(data){
              console.log(data);
              console.log(this);
           }.bind(this)
        );
    }
```

or use `arrow function` it will do this job for you, you don't need to worry about method binding, use this:

```
       constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { 'videos' : []};
            YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'surfboards'}, (data)=>{
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log(this);
            });
        }
```